# Error happend at the time installation of SQL Server 2008 on Windows 7

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, database-administration

I got below error at the time of installing SQL Server 2008 on Windows 7:

[image]

Comment: Installation problems probably don't belong here in a coding community. Try dba perhaps?

Comment: Can you get SQL 2008 R2? Installing SQL 2008 got a lot of problems.

Comment: Post the question on the Database Administrators site.

Answer (score 0):

I think, It was because of corrupted installation file.
After that, i downloaded new installation file from Microsoft site, it installed properly.